# How to sort result set in order of matching words

Tags: elasticsearch, search

How to sort result set in order of matching words?

I have a couple words "heinz meyer"

my query returns:

- Heinz A. Meyer
- Heinz Meyer GmbH Heizung-Sanitär
- Heinz Meyer
- Karl-Heinz Meyer GmbH

but i need, order by positions matching like next :

- Heinz Meyer
- Heinz Meyer GmbH Heizung-Sanitär
- Heinz A. Meyer
- Karl-Heinz Meyer GmbH

my query is:

```
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "wildcard": {
                        "name": "heinz*"
                    }
                }, {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "name": "meyer*"
                    }
                }],
                "must_not": [],
                "should": [],
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [{
                            "range": {
                                "latestRevenueStatistics.revenue": {
                                    "gte": "0",
                                    "lte": "40000000"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "range": {
                                "latestRevenueStatistics.number_of_employees": {
                                    "gte": "0",
                                    "lte": "300"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "addresses.postal_code_length": 5
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "from": 0,
        "size": 10
    }
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "wildcard": {
                    "name": "heinz*"
                }
            }, {
                "wildcard": {
                    "name": "mayer*"
                }
            }, {
                "span_near": {
                    "clauses": [{
                        "span_term": {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "heinz"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "span_term": {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "mayer"
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    "slop": 4,
                    "in_order": true
                }
            }],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": [{
                "span_first": {
                    "match": {
                        "span_term": {
                            "name": "heinz"
                        }
                    },
                    "end": 1
                }
            }, {
                "span_first": {
                    "match": {
                        "span_term": {
                            "name": "mayer"
                        }
                    },
                    "end": 2
                }
            }],
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "range": {
                            "latestRevenueStatistics.revenue": {
                                "gte": "0",
                                "lte": "40000000"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "range": {
                            "latestRevenueStatistics.number_of_employees": {
                                "gte": "0",
                                "lte": "300"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "addresses.postal_code_length": 5
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the match query using combination of [Span First](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-first-query.html), [Span Term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-term-query.html) and [Span Near Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html)

For the sake of simplicity, I've created a sample index with only one field labeled `name` of type [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) along with the below documents.

### Documents:

```
POST sortindex/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Heinz A. Meyer"
}

POST sortindex/_doc/2
{
  "name": "Heinz Meyer GmbH Heizung-Sanitär"
}

POST sortindex/_doc/3
{
  "name": "Heinz Meyer"
}

POST sortindex/_doc/4
{
  "name": "Karl-Heinz Meyer GmbH"
}
```

### Query:

```
POST sortindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "span_near": {               <---- Span Near Query
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_term": {         <---- Span Term Query
                  "name": {
                    "value": "heinz"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "name": {
                    "value": "meyer"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 4,                 <---- Retrieve all docs having both heinz and meyer with distance of <= 4 words
            "in_order": true           <---- Heinz must always come before Meyer 
          }     
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "span_first": {              <---- Span First Query
            "match": {
              "span_term": {           <---- Span Term Query
                "name": "heinz"
              }
            },
            "end": 1                   <----  Retrieve docs having heinz's postition <= 1 and > 0 i.e. the first word
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that `Span Near` is placed in `must` clause whereas `Span First` is placed in `should` clause. That way the documents conforming to the `should` clause would get higher score as compared to the ones that doesn't match.

Internally for both, we search using `Span Term` which is nothing but like a term query but it is specifically mean for using with Span Queries.

I'd suggest you to go through the links if you would like to understand more on [Span Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html).

From the link:

> Span queries are low-level positional queries which provide expert
>   control over the order and proximity of the specified terms. These are
>   typically used to implement very specific queries on legal documents
>   or patents.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.38327998,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "sortindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.38327998,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Heinz Meyer"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sortindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.26893127,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Heinz Meyer GmbH Heizung-Sanitär"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sortindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.25940484,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Heinz A. Meyer"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sortindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.19908611,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Karl-Heinz Meyer GmbH"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can go ahead and add the above query to the one you have.

Hope this helps!